# Add partition to Windows XP Guest after extending Logical Volume on host?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, virtual-machine, ntfs, lvm

How do I add a partition to a Windows XP Guest after extending the Logical Volume on the host?

I have a CentOS 6 Server running several virtual machines, one of which is a Windows XP Guest. The Windows XP guest is installed on an LVM partition that is formated as NTFS. KVM+Virsh is used for virtualization.

In `Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Management`:
There was a single Drive `C:` that took all 20GB of a 20GB disk.

On the host machine, I extended the LV that Windows is on using:

`lvextend -L25G /dev/main_vg/vm_xpvm0`

The resize was successful and the LV is now 25GB.

When I reboot the Windows Guest, in `Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Management`, Windows still thinks that the physical drive is 20GB. I expected to find the `C:` drive as a 20GB partition on a 25GB disk, leaving 5GB of space that I could format and mount as `D:`.

How do I make Windows recognize that the physical disk has changed size so that I can use that new free space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer- shut down the Windows VM, wait a few minutes and then start the VM. The new space will then appear. A "soft" reboot with the reboot command isn't enough to get Windows to recognize the hardware change, which is why it wasn't working for me on a reboot.